# Arel: How to write attr = NULL in arel speak?

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, arel

I have an issue with arel: I want to force something like "attr = NULL" using Arel. Arel allows me to do something like this:

```
table = obj.arel_table # obj has attr
table[:attr].eq(nil) # returns ''objs'.'attr' IS NULL'
```

this is fair, since in queries this is the right thing to do. But on updates, I want to be able to set something to NULL, and preferably without having to write the SQL myself (update_all from AR doesn't support ARel-like functionality on collections: objs.things.update_all(:created_at => nil). this breaks). I'm trying basically to do that code block inside the update_all call recurring to arel and to_sql functionalities. Can this be possible?

Comment: Are you sure that the created_at column allows null values? How exactly does your example break?

Answer (score 3):

I'm just reediting the whole answer, as I got your question wrongly.

The way to query if an attribute is null is with `table[:attr].eq(nil)` or in rails `Model.where(attribute: nil)`

If you want to set a value to null when updating, just set that value to nil and let rails take care about it (I'm just talking about rails because you tagged it in your question).

Something like:

`@object.update_attributes(field: nil)`

### Original answer

You just need to pass `nil` to `eq`:

```rb
table[:attr].eq(nil)
```

that generates `where attr is null`

Answer (score -1):

The only way i know to do something like that is using SqlLiteral
something like:

```
table[attr].eq(Arel::Nodes::SqlLiteral.new("NULL"))
```

this will force arel to skip the processor of `nil` and make a simple equality

Comment: This produces `= NULL`, not `IS NULL`.